# SQLite Connection - Injection

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to create a solution with separated classes, so I have:

```
public class RepositorioPadrao<TEntidade> : IRepositorioPadrao<TEntidade>
    where TEntidade : class
{

    public readonly ISQLiteConnection _connection;

    public RepositorioPadrao(ISQLiteConnectionFactory factory)
    {
        _connection = factory.Create("easybudget.sql");
        _connection.CreateTable<TEntidade>();
    }

    public virtual void Inserir(TEntidade objeto)
    {
        _connection.Insert(objeto);
    }
```

Then to use this I have:

```
public class RepositorioDeCategoria : RepositorioPadrao<Categoria>, IRepositorioDeCategoria
{
    public List<Categoria> ObterTudo()
    {
        return _connection
                .Table<Categoria>()
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Descricao)
                .ToList();
    }
}
```

The problem is, that `EasyBudget.Core.Repositorio.RepositorioPadrao<EasyBudget.Core.Dominio.Categoria>` does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your current problem, you could add a constructor to RepositorioDeCategoria that calls the base class:

```
 public RepositorioDeCategoria(ISQLiteConnectionFactory factory)
       : base(factory)
 {
 }
```

---

Alternatively, if you were going to have several `Categoria` and you wanted them to share the same `_connection`, then you might want to reorganise your classes so that they use some form of aggregration instead of inheritance.