# No ctor takes 0 arguments when viewmodel inherits from base class

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm attempting use a base class viewmodel from which all other viewmodels inherit to facilitate sharing between viewmodels.  In the base class I use IoC, passing in an IDataService to the constructor.

```
//IoC
private readonly IDataService _dataService;

public BaseViewModel(IDataService localDataService)
{
    _dataService = localDataService;
}
```

Trouble is when creating a child view model that inherits, the base viewmodel constructor now expects an IDataService.  I've seen this post: [SQLite Connection Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951781/sqlite-connection-injection) but I want to be clear that the proper course is to send the IDataService into the base class from all of my child viewmodels, of which there are about 5. Lacking real IoC understanding I'm concerned this might screw up the dataservice singleton.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: This is standard c# - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230544/c-sharp-error-parent-does-not-contain-a-constructor-that-takes-0-arguments

Comment: Perhaps you didn't see the last sentence of my post, regarding IoC.  What I'm really asking is do I still have a singleton dataservice if I'm passing in IDataService from each child viewmodel.

Comment: IOC is still just c# too. It has to obey the normal c# constructor rules. If it helps, there's a full intro to mvx IOC on https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control